# Is possible redirecting without change the url in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I have this url:

```
http://localhost/search/
```

This returns me this file:

```
http://localhost/search.html
```

Now I want the urls with this structure:

```
http://localhost/search/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?
```

will redirect me to the search.html file too. But **without changing** the url.

For example with this urls:

```
http://localhost/search/women/23/shoes/
http://localhost/search/
http://localhost/search/man/45/shirt/
```

would return the same file:

```
http://localhost/search.html
```

**Note**: *the urls of man and women does not has any existing path in the server.*

Any advice or help would be appreciated. If you need more info, let me know and I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^search/ /search.html
```

Will just work fine. Unless you explicitly request an external redirect, a `RewriteRule` on the same domain will not do one, thus not changing the URL visible in the browser.

Comment: `^/search/` doesn't match the `search` in `localhost/search`. Not in one .htaccess file.

Comment: The one without trailing slash won't be matched indeed, but wasn't specified as required either  :)

Comment: I am talking about the leading slash: [At Per-directory Rewrites: "Therefore, a Pattern with ^/ never matches in per-directory context"](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

Comment: Ah my bad, completely didn't see that - fixed.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't need the rest of url then you can use this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ /search.html [L]
```

if you need to other parameters of url then let me know

**edited version, Niels Keurentjes has a point if you don't need the rest of url**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^search /search.html
```

Comment: The `(.*)` part is obsolete if you're not using the match anyway, the `$` is obsolete since the `*` is greedy by default, and the `[L]` modifier is obsolete if it's the only rule in there anyway.